# Simplify with given equality

Tags: simplifying-expressions, replacement

```
Clear[id, kn, vt, vdd, vo];
id = kn*(vi - vt)^2/2;
vo = vdd - id*rd;
Solve[D[vo, vi] == -1, vi]
```

Output:

```
{{vi->(1+kn rd vt)/(kn rd)}}
```

I want to simplify the result with `vx=1/(kn*rd)`. It should be `vx+vt`. So how to replace with `kn*rd` with `1/vx`?

I try:

```mathematica
Simplify[vi /. Solve[D[vo, vi] == -1, vi][[1]], kn rd == 1/vx]
```

The result is:

```
1/(kn rd) + vt
```

Not `vx+vt`.

The version is 12.0.0.0.

Comment: Just type `Simplify[vi /. Solve[D[vo, vi] == -1, vi][[1]], {kn rd == vx}]` gives `vt+1/vx` (not as you said `vx+vt`

Comment: What `$Version` of Mathematica are you using?

Comment: @Nasser The condition is `vx=1/(kn*rd)`,different from `kn rd == vx`.

Comment: @cvgmt  They wrote `So how to replace with kn*rd with vx` ? And that is what I used. I did not use the code they had. But what they wrote before it. May be that was a typo then.

Comment: @cvgmt It's a typo. I edited it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using `Eliminate`:

```
ToRules@Reverse@Eliminate[{vx == 1/(kn*rd), D[vo, vi] == -1}, {kn, rd}]
(*{vi -> vt + vx}*)
```

Comment: Or maybe `Solve[Eliminate[{vx == 1/(kn*rd), D[vo, vi] == -1}, {kn, rd}] , vi]`.

Answer (score 5):

Also does give the result  `1/(kn rd) + vt` instead of `vx+vt` in Win 11, 13.1 version.

Maybe use another way.

```
Clear[id, kn, vt, vdd, vo];
id = kn*(vi - vt)^2/2;
vo = vdd - id*rd;
Reduce[{D[vo, vi] == -1, vx == 1/(kn*rd)}, {vi}]
% // Last
```

> `rd vx != 0 && kn == 1/(rd vx) && vi == vt + vx`.

> `vi == vt + vx`

Or

```
Solve[{D[vo, vi] == -1, vx == 1/(kn*rd)}, {vi}, {rd}]
```

> `{{vi -> vt + vx}}`

Answer (score 3):

There are already some excellent answers, but I don't see why not using a replacement rule

```
id = kn*(vi - vt)^2/2;
vo = vdd - id*rd;
Solve[D[vo, vi] == -1, vi]
```

and then

```
Simplify[vi /. Solve[D[vo, vi] == -1, vi]] /. 1/(kn rd) :> vx // First
```

> `vt + vx`

Comment: `Simplify[vi /. Solve[D[vo, vi] == -1, vi]] /. 1/(kn rd) :> vx // First` does work, but `Simplify[vi /. Solve[D[vo, vi] == -1, vi]] /. (kn rd) :> 1/vx // First` doesn't, the result is `1/(kn rd)+vt`.

Comment: @Tokubara hi, thanks for your comment. you can try the alternative `First@Simplify[vi /. Solve[D[vo, vi] == -1, vi]] /. kn :> 1/(rd vx)` which works, right?